# Changing vim cursor's shape into a vertical highlighted line

Tags: vim

I have seen several vim cursors that look similar to this 
[image: vim cursor screenshot]

How can I do this ?

Comment: [:h cursorcolumn](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27cursorcolumn%27)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To set the horizontal and vertical lines, you have to `set` these things.

```
  :set cursorcolumn               // for Column
  :set cursorline                 // for showing the line.
```

Answer (score 7):

As @ryuichiro has commented, you're looking for `cursorcolumn`.

Here's a [vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Highlight_current_line) that goes in to depth about configuring this

From that wiki

> ```
> :hi CursorLine   cterm=underline ctermbg=darkred ctermfg=white guibg=darkred guifg=white
> :hi CursorColumn cterm=NONE ctermbg=darkred ctermfg=white guibg=darkred guifg=white
> ```

Also

```
:set cursorline
:set cursorcolumn
```